謎のエラー：Received instead: learning_rate=MultiOptimizerV3
下記のコードで OptimizerV2 を Optimizer に変えたところOptimizerの初期化時にエラーが出るようになってしまいました。
コードは自分が書いたものではなく、自分の知識も不足しているためよく理解できていないです。
エラーメッセージ:
ValueError: Argument learning_rate should be float, or an instance of LearningRateSchedule, or a callable (that takes in the current iteration value and returns the corresponding learning rate value). Received instead: learning_rate=MultiOptimizerV3

目的
他の部分ではtensorflow.kerasを使用しており、ここでtensorflow.python.kerasを使うと以下のようなエラーが出るためライブラリのインポート元をそろえようとしている
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <__main__.MultiOptimizerV3 object at 0x00000163F5AFB860>

インスタンス作成側のコード
multiOpt = MultiOptimizerV3(belief=True, learning_rate=0.001,momentum=0.9,rho=0.999)

実行したコード(https://qiita.com/T-STAR/items/08ff024512ce56958ddc)
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.optimizer_v2 import OptimizerV2
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Optimizer #追加部分
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend_config
class MultiOptimizerV3(Optimizer): #ここをOptimizerV2からOptimizerへ変更しました
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.0, centered=True, rho=0.0, centered_v=True, epsilon=1e-7, belief=False, name='MultiOptimizerV3', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
        self._set_hyper('learning_rate', kwargs.get('lr', learning_rate))
        self._set_hyper('decay', self._initial_decay)
        self.momentum = momentum
        self.centered = centered if momentum!=0.0 else False
        self.rho = rho
        self.centered_v = centered_v if rho!=0.0 else False
        self.epsilon = epsilon or backend_config.epsilon()
        self.belief = belief if rho!=0.0 and momentum!=0.0 else False

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(MultiOptimizerV3, self).get_config()
        config.update({
            'learning_rate': self._serialize_hyperparameter('learning_rate'),
            'decay': self._serialize_hyperparameter('decay'),
            'momentum': self.momentum,
            'centered': self.centered,
            'rho': self.rho,
            'centered_v': self.centered_v,
            'epsilon': self.epsilon,
            'belief': self.belief,
        })
        return config
    def _create_slots(self, var_list):
        for var in var_list:
            if self.momentum!=0.0:
                self.add_slot(var, 'm')
            if self.rho!=0.0:
                self.add_slot(var, 'v')

    def _resource_apply_dense(self, grad, var, apply_state=None):
        var_device, var_dtype = var.device, var.dtype.base_dtype
        lr_t = self._decayed_lr(var_dtype)
        local_step = tf.cast(self.iterations+1, var_dtype)

        updates = []

        if self.momentum!=0.0:
            # MomentumSGD
            m = self.get_slot(var, 'm')
            m_t = m.assign( self.momentum*m + (1.0-self.momentum)*grad )
            if self.centered:
                denominator = 1.0-(self.momentum**local_step)
                m_t_hat = m_t / denominator
            else:
                m_t_hat = m_t
            updates.append(m_t)
        else:
            m_t_hat = grad


        if self.rho!=0.0:
            #RMSprop
            if self.belief: # AdaBelief
                g2 = (grad-m_t)**2
                epsilon_b = self.epsilon
            else:
                g2 = grad**2
                epsilon_b = 0.0

            v = self.get_slot(var, 'v')
            v_t = v.assign( self.rho*v + (1.0-self.rho)*g2 )

            if self.centered_v:
                denominator = 1.0-(self.rho**local_step)
                lr_t = lr_t / ((((v_t+epsilon_b)/denominator)**0.5)+self.epsilon)
            else:
                lr_t = lr_t / ((v_t**0.5)+self.epsilon)
            updates.append(v_t)

        # Update var
        var_update = var.assign(var - lr_t*m_t_hat)
        updates.append(var_update)
        return tf.group(*updates)

    def _resource_apply_sparse(self, grad, var, indices):
        raise NotImplementedError("not implemented")

追記：
エラーメッセージ全文はこれです。
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[59], line 83
     81     def _resource_apply_sparse(self, grad, var, indices):
     82         raise NotImplementedError("not implemented")
---> 83 multiOpt = MultiOptimizerV3(belief=True, learning_rate=0.001,momentum=0.9,rho=0.999)

Cell In[59], line 6, in MultiOptimizerV3.__init__(self, learning_rate, momentum, centered, rho, centered_v, epsilon, belief, name, **kwargs)
      5 def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.0, centered=True, rho=0.0, centered_v=True, epsilon=1e-7, belief=False, name='MultiOptimizerV3', **kwargs):
----> 6     super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
      7     self._set_hyper('learning_rate', kwargs.get('lr', learning_rate))
      8     self._set_hyper('decay', self._initial_decay)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\optimizer.py:22, in TFOptimizer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     21 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 22     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     23     self._distribution_strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\optimizers\base_optimizer.py:124, in BaseOptimizer.__init__(self, learning_rate, weight_decay, clipnorm, clipvalue, global_clipnorm, use_ema, ema_momentum, ema_overwrite_frequency, loss_scale_factor, gradient_accumulation_steps, name, **kwargs)
    122 else:
    123     if not isinstance(learning_rate, float):
--> 124         raise ValueError(
    125             "Argument `learning_rate` should be float, or an instance "
    126             "of LearningRateSchedule, or a callable "
    127             "(that takes in the current iteration value "
    128             "and returns the corresponding learning rate value). "
    129             f"Received instead: learning_rate={learning_rate}"
    130         )
    131     with backend.name_scope(self.name, caller=self):
    132         learning_rate = backend.Variable(
    133             learning_rate,
    134             name="learning_rate",
   (...)
    137             aggregation="only_first_replica",
    138         )


learning_rate が __init__の一番最初の仮引数なのでこれが関係している気はします。

他人が書いたコードであるなら、出典を明記してください。また、コードの書き換えはどういった意図で行いましたか？ (どのような結果になることを期待している？)

エラー発生行はどこでしょうか？またエラーメッセージは掲載のもので全てですか？

失礼しました。
引用元はこちらです。https://qiita.com/T-STAR/items/08ff024512ce56958ddc
書き換えの目的は、他の部分ではtensorflow.kerasを使用しているためここでtensorflow.python.kerasを使うと以下のようなエラーが出るからです。
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <main.MultiOptimizerV3 object at 0x00000163F5AFB860>
エラーの全文は質問文の方に追記しますが、寝ぼけていてエラーをよく読んでおらずエラーの発生個所が書いてあることに気が付いていませんでした。すみません。

こう書き換えたところ、別のエラーは出ましたがこの問題自体は解決しました。
super().__init__(name=name,learning_rate=learning_rate,**kwargs)


google翻訳
ValueError: 引数learning_rateはfloat、LearningRateScheduleのインスタンス、または呼び出し可能オブジェクト(現在の反復値を受け取り、対応する学習率値を返す)である必要があります。代わりに次の値を受け取りました: learning_rate=MultiOptimizerV3

謎というのはそういう意味ではなく、optimizerのバージョンを変えただけで数値が入るべきところにクラスが入ったり今回は違いますがbool値が入ったりしていたからです。多分第一引数の値がlerning_rateに入っている状態です。

@waco そのように尋ねたいこと・答えて欲しいことを質問文に記述してください。

分かりました。記述しました。ご返信ありがとうございます。

 super().__init__(
            name=name,
            learning_rate=learning_rate,
            **kwargs
        )

本当にすみません。こう書き換えたところ、別のエラーは出ましたがこの問題は解決しました。お時間をとってしまいすみません。
